# Angular zip file download issue AWS

Tags: c#, angular

I have implemented a download zip file functionality in angular application. This code works fine locally. The user double clicks the downloaded zip file. This opens up the archive, the user then double clicks the file inside this opens up correctly. However when this application is deployed on AWS linux server, when user opens the archive and double clicks the file inside it to open it, it throws an error as "file corrupt". However unzipping the folder manually and then double clicking the file inside it opens up the file.

I have tried multiple ways but this error seems to persist. Has any one faced such an issue? Let me know your ideas.

Can't upload code due to data security restrictions here.

Comment: What code, what error, and what language are you using? `Angular` is a Javascript framework. Since you mention Linux, I assume the application targets .NET Core?

Comment: `Can't upload code due to data security restrictions here.` then you won't get any answers. There are no data security restrictions that prevent you from creating a simple, minimal example from scratch that can reproduce the problem. Since you mention `AWS Linux` I assume your application is a .NET Core app? You can try running the code inside Windows 10's WSL to see whether you can reproduce the problem

Comment: yes my application is a .net core application. There is no error, but the zip when double clicked a pop says "compressed (zipped) folders error. windows cannot complete the extraction. the destination file could not be created." However when i unarchive/ unzip the file instead of double click, the file opens up.

Comment: So where's the code that creates it? You still haven't provided any information

Comment: cant provide code, mostly am using blob

Comment: Then you can't get an answer. It's impossible to guess what's going on and most likely the code itself is wrong. If you write some stuff to a GZipStream you'll get something that's not a valid `.z` or `.zip` file but archive utilities can still use by checking the file header. Did you use GZipStream? ZipPackage? SharpZipLib? Some other library? How can anyone guess?

Comment: i am using ZipFile of System.IO.Compression